# How to use the same app for tasks in different packages in Celery

Tags: python, celery

Let's say I have a package A that defines some Celery tasks:

```
app = Celery('tasks')

@app.task
def doA():
    return "doA"
```

I have also a package B that do the same thing:

```
 app = Celery('tasks')

 @app.task
 def doB():
     return "doB"
```

Then I have a package C that wraps both A and B:

```
import package_a
import package_b
#Of course I can call doA and doB asynchronously
package_a.doA.delay()
package_a.doB.delay()
```

But in package C how can I start a worker (define a global app object) that includes both tasks in package A and B ?

Answer (score 0):

In your package_c you can add the following celery configuration:

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = [
    'package_a',
    'package_b',
  ]
```

Then the worker will find the tasks from A and B

Comment: Package C is the package that call tasks in A and B, Package C is not  worker